# install maven failed, use export M2_HOME path in vim,cannot use terminal as usual,how to fix it?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, maven

```
Last login: Tue Sep 12 22:01:16 on ttys000
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/xxx/Desktop/maven3.5.0': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: /Users/xxx/.profile: No such file or directory xxx-MacBook-Pro:~ xxx$
```

I just want to install maven, I used 
brew install maven
and I failed
Then I download binary.zip from official website and input a series of cmd.
I closed terminal and I restart terminal. now I got those (above)

how to deal with it?

Comment: It looks as if one of the bash .`rc` files has statements like `export PATH = /usr/local/bin:......`, where it should be `export PATH=/usr/local/....`. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I would suggest to simply download the `apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.tar.gz` file and unpackage it somewhere it is available via path...like `/usr/local/` and add it to the path...that's it...I wouldn't go via brew etc.